# Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a subgroup with respect to the sum operation.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a subgroup with respect to the sum operation. Show that, in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$, you have that $\overline{S} = S$ or $\overline{S} = \mathbb{R}$.
>
> (i) Is the set of natural numbers with the usual sum a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, for example?
>
> (ii) Why let's consider the $a= \inf\{x \in S : x > 0\}$ and analyze cases $a > 0$ and $a = 0$?

I didn't understand that tip. Can someone help me please???

Comment: If $a = 0$, it means that you can find elements in $S$ that are arbitrarily small. Adding such elements with itself many times (or their inverses), you can use this to prove that $\overline{S}$ must be all of $\mathbb{R}$.
Conversely, if $a > 0$, it implies that every two elements of $S$ must be at least a distance $a$ apart from each other. Use this to prove that $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @BastiaanCnossen Can you help me?

Comment: @IsadoraSuhadolnick Bastian already helped you a lot!!!!

Comment: I would very much like to understand this issue, @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @IsadoraSuhadolnick  let $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ be arbitrary.  Let $ \varepsilon > 0 $ be arbitrary.  We must construct an element $ s \in S $ which is within $ \varepsilon $ of $ x $... this is precisely what it means to have $ x \in \bar{S} $.

Comment: I still don't understand :(

Comment: @IsadoraSuhadolnick then I suggest you do some easier problems about closures of sets in $ \mathbb{R} $ and then come back to this one.